# Customloading screen is covering only half the scene

Tags: javascript, css, screen, loading, babylonjs

I have an issue using a custom loading screen. When I displaying the loading screen it only covers half the scene: Image while loading[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilQL3.png)

This is the code I use for displaying the loading screen:

```
BABYLON.DefaultLoadingScreen.prototype.displayLoadingUI = function() {
    if (document.getElementById("customLoadingScreenDiv")) {
      document.getElementById("customLoadingScreenDiv").style.display =
        "initial";
      return;
    }

    this._loadingDiv = document.createElement("div");
    this._loadingDiv.id = "customLoadingScreenDiv";
    this._loadingDiv.style.color = "white";
    this._loadingDiv.style.height = "1000px";
    this._loadingDiv.style.width = "100%";
    this._loadingDiv.style.alignContent = "center";
    this._loadingDiv.style.marginTop = "-50%";
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "[link to gif]";
    img.style.position = "center";
    this._loadingDiv.appendChild(img);

    this._resizeLoadingUI();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this._resizeLoadingUI);
    document.body.appendChild(this._loadingDiv);
  };

  BABYLON.DefaultLoadingScreen.prototype.hideLoadingUI = function() {
    document.getElementById("customLoadingScreenDiv").style.display =
      "none";
  };
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is more of a CSS problem than actualy any of the tags you tagged the question.

My solution would be:

```
this._loadingDiv.style.color = "white";
this._loadingDiv.style.height = "100vh";
this._loadingDiv.style.width = "100%";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didnt work. When I first click the scene it works just fine but as soon as I click a mesh the screen of my application where the babylon scene is imbeded increases in some way and now I need to scroll down the scene when I want to reach certain buttons. I think maybe that is causing it.                                                 Before: https://imgur.com/a/QKmTNYw                                                                            After: https://imgur.com/a/9vVD4TN

Answer (score 0):

That `margin-top: -50%` is probably causing it. Are you trying to vertically and horizontally center that div? The `alignContent` is also doing nothing without declaring it as `display: flex` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the margin is not causing it. I tried to move the screen to the top as far as possible thats because I used -50%.